# ffmpeg error mb_type 7802 in P slice too large at 50 35kbps

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, rtmp

When I decode a `h264 rtmp` stream with `ffmpeg` I am getting the following error in the console:

`[h264 @ 02c3af20] mb_type 7802 in P slice too large at 50 35kbps
[h264 @ 02c3af20] error while decoding MB 50 35`

ffmpeg can't play my `h264 rtmp` stream but if I en-decode `vp6 rtmp` stream there is no problem. Why is this?

Answer (score 1):

Because your H.264 stream is broken (out of spec) or you incorrectly decoding stream. It was broken either during encoding or during network transfer.

Comment: if I use the vlc or flash to play this stream ,it is ok,why??

Comment: why the VLC Player can play this stream? how to set the FFMPEG? thanks for your reply!!

Comment: When i read frame from stream.it will be lock in av_read_frame function after A few seconds.
printf("add packet 0\n");
int ret = av_read_frame(m_format_ctx, pkt);
printf("add packet 1\n"); 
when it print "add packet 0",the "add packet 1" string do not appear,the av_read_frame has no return .

Comment: If you want useful answers then you need to provide more useful info for input. Like what exactly you do with command lines and parts of the code for encoding/decoding, muxing/demuxing.

Comment: Could you give me your email?i want to send it to you.thanks for your replay!!

Comment: you can download source code from https://github.com/Jackarain/avplayer
and my rtmp stream is rtmp://111.90.185.153/test/855crovd1 live=1
you can test it.
thanks!!!!